# Fastest android version to emulate for jqm+cordova development?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-virtual-device

i'm having some debug speed problems due to my pc low specs, I've noticed that emulating some android versions run faster than anothers, I searched for this but i can only find performance tips about cpu speed/other enhancments, but nothing about the android version that may run faster by emulation. What is your opinion ?

Thanks

Comment: For those who visit with same question, i find emulating the 4.0 android version faster than with 2.3.x and 4.1.x+

Comment: I've found it fastest to develop 80~90% with chrome and then only afterwards stick it into android and test and complete.  For most projects this works very nicely, however if one is doing heavy usage of phone specific features (e.g. camera, gps, etc.) it's not suitable.  None of the emulators have given me a great performance.  I would recommend looking at a cheap android physical device, will save you lots of time in the end.

Comment: True, i just started to add some native features and started to use an android device for testing, nothing compared to emulator